# Uniqueness of solution to linear first-order ODE with singular points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve a linear first-order ODE for $y(x)$, $x\in[0,1]$,
$$ \gamma(x)y'-ay=-a\gamma(x),\quad y(0)=0, $$
where $\gamma(x)$ is a known function with $\gamma(0)=0$, and $a>0$ is a known constant.

Because $\gamma(0)=0$ makes $x=0$ a singular point, does this ODE have unique solution if additional condition $y'(0)=1$ is given? If yes, how to prove it (or is there any existing theorem showing this)?

*Some background of my question:* $F(x)$ and $f(x)$ are the distribution function and density function of random variable $X$ on support $[0,1]$. Let $y(x)=F(x)/f(x)$ and function $\gamma(x)=\frac{y(x)}{1+y'(x)/a}$ is known. I want to get the distribution of $X$ by figuring out function $y(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

In general you cannot expect to have a solution. Consider the particular case $\gamma(x)=b\,x$. If $a\ne b$, then
$$
y(x)=\frac{a\,b}{a-b}\,x
$$
satisfies the differential equation and $y(0)=0$. If moreover $b=a/(a+1)$, then $y'(0)=1$. On the other hand, if $a=b$, then the general solution is $y(x)=C\,x+a\,x\,\log x$, which is not $C^1$ at $x=0$.

Now suppose that $\int_0^xds/\gamma(s)<\infty$ and let $g(x)=a\int_0^xds/\gamma(s)$. Then the general solution is
$$
y(x)=C\,e^{g(x)}-a\,e^{g(x)}\int_0^x\,e^{-g(s)}\,ds.
$$
There is only one solution with$y(0)=0$, namely
$$
y(x)=-a\,e^{g(x)}\int_0^x\,e^{-g(s)}\,ds.
$$
Wether it satisfies $y'(0)=1$ will depend on $a$ and $\gamma$.